# Rewrite CASE in COALESCE (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have code in my sql script, that wrote using CASE

Here is it

```
CASE WHEN b.ContactId IS NULL THEN a.ContactId ELSE b.ContactId END AS ContactId,
CASE WHEN b.LastActivityDate IS NULL THEN a.LastActivityDate ELSE b.LastActivityDate END AS LastActivityDate,
CASE WHEN b.ActivityType IS NULL THEN a.ActivityType ELSE b.ActivityType END AS ActivityType,
CASE WHEN b.ActionPersonName IS NULL THEN a.ActionPersonName ELSE b.ActionPersonName END AS ActionPersonName
```

I want to rewrite it using COALESCE. How I can do this correctly?

Comment: Can you include the full query, assuming it would neatly fit in the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to let columns of  `b` to  be the first parameter, columns of  `a` 
to be the second parameter.

[COALESCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> Evaluates the arguments in order and returns the current value of the first expression that initially does not evaluate to `NULL`

```
COALESCE(b.ContactId,a.ContactId) AS ContactId,
COALESCE(b.LastActivityDate,a.LastActivityDate) AS LastActivityDate,
COALESCE(b.ActivityType,a.ActivityType) AS ActivityType,
COALESCE(b.ActionPersonName,a.ActionPersonName) AS ActionPersonName
```

Comment: Yeah. It helps. Thank's!

Answer (score 1):

1st Null check column will be 1st parameter in `COALESCE`

```
COALESCE(b.ContactId,a.ContactId)  AS ContactId,
   COALESCE(b.LastActivityDate,a.LastActivityDate)  AS LastActivityDate,
   COALESCE(b.ActivityType,a.ActivityType,)  AS ActivityType,
    COALESCE(b.ActionPersonName,a.ActionPersonName)  AS ActionPersonName
```